# How do you add .environment(...) to your ContentView() when you don't have a scene delegate (SwiftUI)?

Tags: swift, swiftui, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Normally when you create a new swiftUI app, you have this scene delegate:

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

and you have your contentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {}
```

I would like to add .environment to contentView as follows:

```
ContentView()
.environment(\.managedObjectContext, yourCoreDataContext)
```

But as I initially created my app as a swift UIKit app I don't have this scene delegate to do this. How can I add the environment?

(I am using UIHostingController to show my swiftUI view)

Comment: You can’t, you can add it at the ContentView like the Xcode sample and then all the views below will have access.

Comment: @loremipsum I didn't get it, the Xcode sample?

Comment: Create a new project with SwiftUI and CoreData. Xcode provides a sample.

Comment: So you say I should add the sample to my current project (the sample is actually the @main code above in the post)

Comment: Look at how they are creating and populating the environment wrapper, you can’t have it in the content view but you can inject it there so the subviews can have access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you created UIKit project with CoreData then view context is in AppDelegate, so the code of presenting controller with ContentView might look like

```
    if let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
        let viewContext = delegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView:
            ContentView()
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, viewContext)
        )
        self.present(controller, animated: true)
    }
```